# What is 'semantic highlighting' option in MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Under 'Syntax highlighting' there is an option for 'enable semantic highlighting'. What does that do differently than regular intellisense/autocomplete/highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without semantic highlight MD does only simple highlighting, only based on the rules of the language - like keywords, strings, digits.

Semantic highlighting, well, as the name suggests, analyzes the meaning of tokens. At the present time, for C# I think it only highlights tokens that represent a type name. 
In the future a wider range of highlighting is possible, for example a local variables.

And the last thing - it is not related to the intellisense/autocomplete feature.

Comment: Note also that the current implementation slows down the editor a *lot*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that looks like highlighting the objects and variable types explained here: http://zwabel.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/c-ide-evolution-from-syntax-highlighting-to-semantic-highlighting/

Anymore info on it would be good.